# Sometimes Bitmap decoding return SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null and it displays corrupted image

Tags: android, sockets, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory, skia

I developed the below class to receive image sent with header (22 bytes) first I decode the header to check the image correctness then I decode the image but not all images are decoded sometimes it returns with `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`. I am using [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) Android tutorial to `inSampleImage`.

```
public class SocketServerStreamDataThread extends Thread {

    private Socket streamSocket;
    MainActivity mainActivity ;
    ImageView  displayedImage ;

    Bitmap bitmapImageToDisplay = null;
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1048576];

    boolean result ;

    protected static boolean mReceivingStop; // Flag used to start and stop transmitting data

    SocketServerStreamDataThread(Socket socket, MainActivity mainActivityReceived, ImageView displayedImageView) {
        streamSocket = socket;
        // received activity to work on it in our java file
        mainActivity = mainActivityReceived ;
        // received image UI component to display
        displayedImage = displayedImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Receiving the image */
        try {
            DecodeData decodeData = new DecodeData();
            // call DecodeData to get Image data from stream
            while (mReceivingStop == false) {
                if (bitmapImageToDisplay == null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = streamSocket.getInputStream();
                    if (inputStream.read(dataBuffer) > -1) {
                        // Call the class to decode received stream and return integer with the state of the decoding of the received data
                        // result = 0  ; means that decoding header is successful.
                        // result = -1 ; means that there is a problem in decoding header.
                        byte [] dataHeaderReceived = Arrays.copyOf(dataBuffer, 23) ;
                        result = decodeData.iDecodeReceiveData(dataHeaderReceived);
                        // Evalute the received data
                        if (result == false) {
                            /* Fault on application */
                            /* Close socket */
                            streamSocket.close();
                            mReceivingStop = true;
                        }

                        if (result == true) {
                            /* Data have been received */
                            /* Show image */
                            BitmapFactory.Options imageOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            imageOption.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainActivity.getResources(), R.id.display_image, imageOption);
                            imageOption.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize (imageOption, 550, 435) ;
                            imageOption.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                            bitmapImageToDisplay = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataBuffer, 23, decodeData.imageSize, imageOption);

                            if (bitmapImageToDisplay != null) {
                                mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //try to display to image
                                        displayedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapImageToDisplay);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    SystemClock.sleep(300);
                    bitmapImageToDisplay = null ;
                }
            }
            streamSocket.close();
            mReceivingStop = true;

            mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringBuilder eMsg = new StringBuilder();
            eMsg.append("Something wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            final String eMessage=eMsg.toString();
            // final String eMsg = "Something wrong: " + e.getMessage();

            mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, eMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(streamSocket != null){
                try {
                    streamSocket.close();
                    mReceivingStop = true ;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1307K, 27% free 13676K/18596K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1306K, 27% free 13676K/18596K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1607K, 29% free 13376K/18596K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1255K, 27% free 13728K/18596K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
```

Comment: I used SystemClock.sleep(300); to give time for decoding process as before it was not catching to decode and the message of decode return false was appearing

Comment: What is `DecodeData`? And where are you getting a `resId` from?

Comment: DecodeData is class to decode the header of the received image to get image attributes also to know the image size

Answer (score 0):

Loading bitmaps on Android is a large and fairly complex topic. Which is why I recommend using one of the proven libraries to handle it for you; such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). These libraries will handle many of the pitfalls that come with loading bitmaps for you; including memory constraints, caching and threading.

---

If you really want to go at alone you will have to face these problems yourself. The `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` is what the `BitmapFactory.decode...` methods spit out if the bitmap cannot be decoded correctly, which can be caused by a number of issues. I do not know exactly what is causing this, but I do see a number of issues in your code.

First, you pass the `MainActivity` into the `Thread`, this is just asking for trouble. Instead you should only need to pass the `ImageView` into to the `Thread`. And make sure you use a `WeakReference`, otherwise you risk leaking your `Context`:

```
WeakReference<ImageView> mDisplayedImageView;

SocketServerStreamDataThread(Socket socket, ImageView imageView) {
    mDisplayedImageView = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
    ...
}
```

Next, you are using a drawable resource to decode the bounds of the `Bitmap`, but then you are trying to obtain a `Bitmap` from a `Socket` connection. Instead you should decode the bounds using the `InputStream`:

```
BufferedInputStream inBounds = new BufferedInputStream(streamSocket.getInputStream());

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inBounds, null, options);

options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

inBounds.close();
```

And you will not need to have a separate `DecodeData` class, as `BitmapFactory` has a method to decode a stream as well:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(streamSocket.getInputStream());

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);

in.close();
```

Lastly, if you are using `Thread.sleep()` or `SystemClock.sleep()` to overcome some obstacle, you should probably rethink your solution. These are just the issues I noticed on a quick look through. If you really want to continue without the aid of a library, I suggest doing some more research on how to load bitmaps efficiently; a good starting point is [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: thanks for your help, but first the received image added with 22 special byte header that need to be decoded so that I am using DecodeData class it can not be decoded with BitmapFactory so I need first to read the first 22 byte to read special data. second I am using 'SystemClock.sleep()' to overcome this problem that I can not find the source of it.Also I am passing 'MainActivity' to use 'runOnUiThread' I do not know about 'WeakReference' I will search about it if it is a solution.

Comment: I have a question, Are Picasso or Glide include an image decoder inside instead of 'BitmapFactory.decode'?

Comment: As far as I know Picasso, Glide and Fresco all use the `BitmapFactory.decode...` methods to decode images, they do not contain separate decoders.

Comment: You should also be using a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), along with callbacks, instead of passing the `MainActivity` around.